# MySQL Effects of (very) high ID (PK) in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a script that loads and processes an XML feed every night. During the processing of the feed all the elements are saved to a database table. Before the insert loop starts, all the existing records are removed from the database. 
There are usually about 3.000 elements that need to be saved as records, so the ID, which is PK, is increasing pretty fast.
Actually, within a year, the ID is passing the number 1.000.000. Despite of this high number, the amount or records will not increase this fast and will be around the number of 3.000. 
Is the high ID number a problem for my database performace?

Comment: You say you remove the old data? Why don't you just truncate the table and set the increment value back to 1?

Comment: as @Dieter said it is better to truncate the table, as you're deleting all its records. But even if you don't, I don't think a high id number would have an effect on mysql or its speed.